# How to distribute rows of a long table on multiple pages in html

Tags: html

i'm new in web development, i have a problem to handle the long table. I have a page where have large number of rows it will not look so good to display them on one 1 page. i want to distribute these rows on multiple pages, like if i have 24 rows i want to display only 3 rows on a page so with this complete table will shown on 8 pages. 
so is there have any way to do this & how?

Thanks in advance

Comment: that is a process that as a beginner, you might want to look up more tutorials on pagination. There are a number of ways you can do that either with dynamic languages such as php or java(JQuery/Ajax). It'd be too much to do a coding example here.

Answer (score 2):

You need a [**pagination**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination) technique. There a different techniques for different languages.

You might use a server (e.g. with php) or client side pagination technique (e.g. [with jQuery](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination)). See this jQuery example http://web.enavu.com/demos/paginate/