# How to make dynamic page navigation for more than 1 pages of same thing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

In my 1st question i asked about how i can distribute a many rows on different pages & got a answer to you the pagination technique, i used that but in that have 1 problem all pages have the same link but i want they should have different, so anybody know any other technique or way through which we can do that. if don't have any option like that then if we have different html pages so we can make any dynamic page navigation for these pages

Thanks in advance.

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=newusers)

please check this page & sea it's page navigation, actually i want like this, i have very long table it has 4 columns & more than 100 rows, i want to show only 2 rows on each page but when user click on page 2 link switch to next 2 rows but also want to update the page address because with this every page will has the different identity,

Comment: the other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873334/how-to-distribute-rows-of-a-long-table-on-multiple-pages-in-html

Answer (score 2):

You should send the page as a GET (url) parameter, so you'd have:

```
<a href="table.php?page=1"> Page 1 </a>
<a href="table.php?page=2"> Page 2 </a>
<a href="table.php?page=3"> Page 3 </a>
<a href="table.php?page=4"> Page 4 </a>
...
```

So the links will be different, and you can return different values depending of the `page` parameter.
Hope this helps, and to have understood what you wanted

Cheers

Comment: But dear i have only this code
in header
<script type="text/javascript" src="paging.js"></script>

under table
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
        var pager = new Pager('results', 3); 
        pager.init(); 
        pager.showPageNav('pager', 'pageNavPosition'); 
        pager.showPage(1);
    //--></script>
in this where should i add these parameters

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=newusers)

please check this page & sea it's page navigation, actually i want like this, i have very long table it has 4 columns & more than 100 rows, i want to show only 2 rows on each page but when user click on page 2 link switch to next 2 rows but also want to update the page address because with this every page will has the different identity,

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a page number as a [query parameter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) in the URL, like this:

```
http://example.com/big-table?page=4
```

- When the main page loads, check the URL for the `page` parameter. If present, load the corresponding page (chunk of rows).
- When changing the page (chunk of rows) make sure to update the corresponding query parameter. For example, if the user is currently viewing the URL above, and clicks a "next" button, you'd want to change the URL to

  ```
  http://example.com/big-table?page=5
  ```

Does that make sense?

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=newusers)

please check this page & sea it's page navigation, actually i want like this, i have very long table it has 4 columns & more than 100 rows, i want to show only 2 rows on each page but when user click on page 2 link switch to next 2 rows but also want to update the page address because with this every page will has the different identity,